# Kotlin lambda custom parameter name does not work with Calendar.getInstance()

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create extension function for Date object that returns a Calendar.

```
fun Date.setTimeToDayEnd() = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
    set(
        this.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        this.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        this.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
        23,
        59,
        59
    )
}.time
```

The problem is I want `this` to refer the `Date`, not the `Calendar` from `apply` lambda. So i try to use named parameter.

```
fun Date.setTimeToDayEnd() = Calendar.getInstance().apply { calendar ->
    set(
        this.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        this.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        this.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
        23,
        59,
        59
    )
}.time
```

But the errors show up. I don't know how to fix this.

[image: errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a scope function without a receiver. You can’t arbitrarily choose whether it uses a receiver or not. In this case you should use `also` instead of `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with `this` erasure when using `apply`, you can use `let` which will not erase the `this` context as it stores the receiver as the lambda argument.

```kotlin
fun Date.setTimeToDayEnd() = Calendar.getInstance().let {
  // this refers to Date
  // it   refers to Calendar
}
```

See Kotlin reference for Scope Functions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html

Comment: this works for `this` and `it` problem, but does not work because `let` returns the result instead of value, hence calling `Calendar.getInstance().let {...}.time` is illegal.